# How do I calculate/count rows in a table

Tags: excel, count, powerbi

| Location | data/time |
| --- | --- |
| New york | 22-02-28 22:00:00 |
| New york | 22-02-27 21:00:00 |
| New york | 22-02-26 20:00:00 |
| New york | 22-02-25 19:00:00 |
| Chicago | 22-02-28 22:00:00 |
| Chicago | 22-02-27 22:00:00 |
| Chicago | 22-02-26 22:00:00 |
| Chicago | 22-02-25 22:00:00 |
| Paris | 22-02-25 22:00:00 |
| Paris | 22-02-25 22:00:00 |

Q1 How can I count how many rows in date/time I have.
So far using `Count = Count(Table1[DateTime])` seems to be counting all rows in this example would 10. What Im looking for would display, NY 4, Chicago 4, Paris 2.

Q2. How would I calculate a percentage. So far Ive tried `(96 - COUNT('Table1'[DateTime]))/96` but that brings back the wrong values. (96 represents the number of entries I'm expecting and Im trying to calculate how many entries are missing in the table)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you asking a Mysql question? A MS-Excel question? A powerBI question? The code you've shown here looks like a spreadsheet formula which makes your question off topic here (BTW in most spreadsheets you would get the results you are asking for with a pivot table).

Comment: @symcbean FYI good questions about Excel Formula are _not_ off topic. (That said, this Q _is_ off topic - requires more details)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your explanation, we are not sure what are you looking for, Power Bi, SQL, or Excel.
I would share with you an approach using a T-SQL Code.

The count can be found using a Group By clause.
You can change it to MySql if something is not compatible.

Power BI: I would recommend you to use a DAX formula to group the dates, similar to the SQL code below.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #LocationTimes;
GO

CREATE TABLE #LocationTimes(
[LocationName]  VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
[EntryTimes] DATETIME2(3) NOT NULL
)
INSERT INTO #LocationTimes
    (
        [LocationName]
      , [EntryTimes]
    )
SELECT
 'New york'
, '2022-02-28 22:00:00' UNION ALL
SELECT
 'New york'
, '2022-02-27 21:00:00' UNION ALL
SELECT
 'New york'
, '2022-02-26 20:00:00' UNION ALL
SELECT
 'New york'
, '2022-02-25 19:00:00' UNION ALL
SELECT
 'Chicago'
, '2022-02-28 22:00:00' UNION ALL
SELECT
 'Chicago'
, '2022-02-27 22:00:00' UNION ALL
SELECT
 'Chicago'
, '2022-02-26 22:00:00' UNION ALL
SELECT
 'Chicago'
, '2022-02-25 22:00:00' UNION ALL
SELECT
 'Paris'
, '2022-02-25 22:00:00' UNION ALL
SELECT
 'Paris'
, '2022-02-25 22:00:00'

SELECT
 [LocationName]
, COUNT(EntryTimes) [COUNT]
FROM
#LocationTimes
GROUP BY
    LocationName

SELECT
 [LocationName]
, [EntryTimes]
, COUNT(EntryTimes) [COUNT]
FROM
#LocationTimes
GROUP BY
    LocationName
  , [EntryTimes]
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is for excel instead of SQL, easiest way to display NY 4, Chicago 4, Paris 2, is by using a pivot table. You can do this by selecting your entire table(including the header), then going to the "Insert" tab on the ribbon and selecting "Pivot table" > From table range.

[Screen shot of where pivot table is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKhe8.png)

From the pivot table pane that comes up on the right, drag and drop locations under the rows section, and datetime under the values section.

[Screen shot of how to set up pivot table fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyiPT.png)

If the data in the original table changes you can right click on your new pivot table and refresh to refresh the pivot table results.

For Q2:
The count function counts the number of rows with numbers in it. Getting the count of a date field will give you a result of 0. You should use the "COUNTA" function instead which would return the number of rows in the range that are not empty.

Percentage calculation would be:

```
=(96-COUNTA(Table11[Datetime]))/96
```

OR if you want to display the actual percentage you can see as a percentage.

```
=((96-COUNTA(Table11[Datetime]))/96)*100
```